# create dylib in mac import in python

Tags: c++, python, macos, dylib

Hi i know how to make Library (dll) in windows with visual studio 2012 with c++
and import in python with ctypes work great

here small example

lib.cpp

```
#define DLLEXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
DLLEXPORT int sum(int a,int b)
{
return (a+b);
}
```

lib.h

```
int sum(int,int);
```

test.py

```
from ctypes import *
mydll=cdll.LoadLibrary('lib.dll')
print mydll.sum(2,2)
```

i try run same code in mac with xcode 4.4 version
when i buld in xcode i get warring message

```
__declspec attribute 'dllexport' is not supported
```

and when import lib.dylib in python i get error

```
AttributeError: dlsym(0x101afba30, sum): symbol not found
```

what i do wrong ?
can some one write simple code how i can make a dylib in mac with xcode correct to import with Ctypes in python 2.6.4

OR

the are is better way to import libaries in python in both system
for mac and win ?

basic i like to write code in windows with visual studio 2012 make dll i
and then simple compiler in mac with xcode and import in python

Comment: You probably did something wrong setting up the way to dylib gets built, because when I build this with a default Xcode 4.4 dylib project, or just from the command line with `clang++ -shared -o lib.dylib lib.cpp`, I get that warning, but then `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('lib.dylib').sum(2, 2)` works fine.

Comment: If you want to get rid of the warning, you should use a different `#define` for each platform (e.g., by using `#ifdef _WIN32`). But that's not affecting your problem.

Comment: thank you for quick reply ! what version python you try to run 2.6.4 ?

Comment: I just tested on two different machines on 11 different Pythons—Apple, python.org, Homebrew, and custom-built, ranging from 2.5.6 up to a recent 3.4 checkout, and all of them do the same thing.

Comment: can you please tell me the steps in xcode you used ? to create new project to make sure i do all correct thank you for your time

Comment: this i do i make new project select os -> framework c++ , then select type i select dynamic library , create and i write cpp and h i run when complite  right in lib.dylib i click show in finder and i copy this dylib.lib last i import in python and i get error :(

Comment: i forget to tell you i used 64 bit for compiler and python maybe this problem ?

Comment: I assumed you used 64-bit, because those are the defaults for Apple's Python 2.6 and for Xcode. And those are the same steps I used (with Xcode 4.4 on the 10.8 machine, and 5.0 on the 10.9 machine). Can you go to the build results, click the details things next to the "Compile Lib.cpp" and "Link" steps, and paste the ridiculously long command lines somewhere that I can read it?

Comment: the problem was never update the dylib because used by python ! , first time when i try ... i remake the project for begin and work great , something last if you know about this when load the lib in python with ctypes mydll=cdll.LoadLibrary('lib.dll') how i can unload after ? thank you very much for your help

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no documented guaranteed way to do it… although if you `import _ctypes` I believe you can `try: _ctypes.dlclose(mydll._handle)` then `except NameError: _ctypes.FreeLibrary(mydll._handle)` or something similar.

Comment: Great Work !!  thank you very much , maybe you know if this possible i have make in win 7 dll to play media , there is way to compiler this in mac with xcode ? because used direct show , #include "Dshow.h"

Comment: Please don't toss in entirely new questions as followups on existing ones. SO is supposed to make it easy for someone with the same problem as you to search and find a question and answer. This means you need to create a new question for each separate thing you want to ask.

Comment: But… it's not possible. DirectShow is part of Windows; it does not exist on any other platform. You'll have to use a different library on each platform (e.g., [`AVFoundation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html) on Mac, if you only need 10.7+), or find a cross-platform wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem was that you already had the dylib loaded into your Python interpreter. Just rebuilding it won't affect what you have loaded into memory.

Just doing another `LoadLibrary` may or may not re-load the library, and there's no way to force it to do so.

There is also no way to unload and reload libraries in `ctypes`. The main reason is that there is no safe way to do so on all platforms—in fact, before 10.4, OS X itself was such a platform. (And Python still has [current source code in the tree](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6a1ce1fd1fc0/Modules/_ctypes/darwin) to support pre-10.4 OS X in `ctypes`.) But also, trying to come up with a model that does things the safe way on every platform isn't exactly trivial. So, `ctypes` doesn't try.

If you really need to do it, the `_ctypes` module underneath `ctypes` generally exports the necessary functions into Python. If you know the names for your platform, you can find them with `help(_ctypes)`, or by looking at [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6a1ce1fd1fc0/Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c).

Briefly, on most modern POSIX platforms (including OS X 10.5+) it's `_ctypes.dlclose(mydll._handle)`, while on Win32, it's `_ctypes.FreeLibrary(mydll._handle)`. In either case, if you ever use `mydll` again (or any functions or values that you were referencing from it), you should pray for a segfault. You may also segfault on exit. And on Windows, it may not actually free the library when you ask it to, and in some cases you have to ask the library if it's ready to unload before you can do so, and there are threading complexities, and… well, just read the [`FreeLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) docs on MSDN, and of course the manpage for [`dlclose(3)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dlclose.3.html) on every POSIX system you care about.

In general, it's a much better idea to just start up a new interpreter process instead.

Comment: For a small example of the complexities involved in unloading a library, consider string constants. If *any* code in your application has stored a pointer to a string constant in a library, unloading the library will make those pointers all become invalid!

Comment: @duskwuff: Thanks for the example; most people don't think beyond the obvious case of keeping references to the functions, but constants are just as much of a problem (and you can have a reference to one without even knowing it, e.g., if a function returns a value without telling you whether it might come from a constant).